# Matlab backslash reordering algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, linear-solver, sparse-matrix, banded-matrix

For the linear system $\mathbf A \mathbf x = \mathbf b$ generated from 2D Poisson equation using the standard central finite difference method,
$$
\mathbf A =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf K & -\mathbf I \\
-\mathbf I & \mathbf K & -\mathbf I \\
& -\mathbf I & \mathbf K & -\mathbf I \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\mathbf I$ is the identity matrix and $\mathbf K$ is the tridiagonal matrix with stencil $[-1 \  4 \ -1]$.

With Matlab backslash, does anyone know what reordering algorithm matlab will use to solve this sparse system?

And in general, how matlab decide wihch reordering algorithm to use?

Comment: Matlab will likely use **(a)** minimum degree (MMD) orderings with QR-based \ and /, or **(b)** [COLAMD](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colamd.html) ordering with the LU-based \ and /, or **(c)** [AMD](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/amd.html) with Cholesky-based \ and /. Source: [the sparse matrix docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-operations.html) and the help page for [`spparms`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spparms.html). To disable the default preordering, run `spparms('autoamd',0); spparms('autommd',0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@gohokies has already given the correct answer in a comment, but just for more context: Matlab backslash calls the UMFPACK (now SuiteSparse) solver for sparse linear systems. The default ordering used by UMFPACK is indeed the Approximate Minimum Degree (AMD) method, or a variation thereof.